# Ruby on Rails: Select model that user has not interacted with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new at Ruby on Rails, but I've spent all day on this trying all different solutions I found online and I've still got nothing.

I have three models: users, tracks, and feeds.

Users is pretty self explanatory,
Tracks are songs that users can upload,
and Feeds are feedbacks that Users leave on each others Tracks

I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feeds

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :feeds, dependent: :destroy

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  has_one :user
```

I need to select the tracks that a user hasn't already left feedback on. I tried:

```
Track.joins(:feeds).where("feeds.user_id != #{current_user.id}").where("tracks.user_id != #{current_user.id}")
```

but that didn't produce anything.

Anybody help?

Extra info if needed:

```
User.column_names()
 => ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "genre", "name", "genre_id", "slug"]

Track.column_names()
 => ["id", "title", "link", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug", "average_feed", "feed_avaliable", "feed_level", "pref_genre", "last_feed"] 

Feed.column_names()
 => ["id", "feedback", "user_id", "track_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "overall", "feed_for"] 

class PageController < ApplicationController

  def feed
    @track = Track.joins(:feeds).where("feeds.user_id != #{current_user.id}").where("tracks.feed_avaliable > '0'").where("tracks.user_id != #{current_user.id}").reorder(feed_level: :asc, last_feed: :desc, created_at: :asc).first()
    @feed = current_user.feeds.build if user_signed_in?
  end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, as Muhammad correctly pointed out, `Feed` should `belongs_to` `User`, not `has_one`.

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This example uses the [`where.not`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) feature introduced in Rails 4.

```
Track.where.not(id: current_user.feeds.select(:track_id))
```

Let's say your user has an id of `42`. This should generate

```
SELECT tracks.* FROM tracks WHERE tracks.id NOT IN (
  SELECT feeds.track_id FROM feeds WHERE feeds.user_id = 42 
)
```

You generally want to avoid string-interpolation in SQL queries at all costs. There are a couple ways to do it safely, but in this case you can just use the ruby interface.

This is preferable to `pluck`ing the ids because that will require two round-trips to the DB, whereas a subquery like this will only need one. But, as always, you should profile your queries to make sure they are fast and check for needed indexes.

Comment: Oh man finally, this worked perfectly. I tried using the where.not feature earlier but I must have not been using it correctly.

Just to make sure I understand, that's basically saying, "choose the tracks where the Track.id is not equal to the track_id of the feeds associated with the user"? I know that's a round about way of saying it, but that's how it makes sense in the code to me.

Comment: The inner query is a set of track ids associated with your user. The outer query excludes any tracks whose id is included in the inner query. If it helps, you can think of the inner query as equivalent to a plain list of ids `(1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

First correct the `Feed` model relationship with `User` model like :

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :user
```

One way to get the `tracks` on which user hasn't left feedback could be :

```
track_ids = current_user.feeds.pluck(:track_id).uniq
@tracks = Track.where("id NOT IN (?)", track_ids)
```

You will get tracks for which user hasn't given feedback.